# Django Model.objects.create vs Model.save()

Tags: python, django

New to Django ORM and had a small question.

If I have a model like:

```
class Person(models.Model):
  id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I can add a new person in the following ways:

```
p1 = Person.objects.create(name="Bob")
```

or

```
p2 = Person(name="Bob")
p2.save()
```

In the first case (p1), I can expect that the "id" field is set (auto-incremented when insertion is done). Can I expect the same in the second case? Does django update the in-memory "Person" object's properties (in this case the id field) once a save is done?

Follow-up questions:

1. Let's say I had another model

```
class Business(models.Model):
  id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
  owner = models.ForeignKey(Person)
```

Does it make a difference if I do

```
b = Business(owner=p1)
b.save()
```

vs

```
b = Business(owner=p2)
b.save()
```

2. What happens if I don't save or create the person object before passing it into Business? e.g.

```
p = Person(name="Bob")
b = Business(owner=p)
b.save()?
```

Comment: yes both are functionally equivalent, the first will be more efficient, since it does a `force_create` so Django will not first check if it can update in the database.

Answer (score 4):

> Can I expect the same in the second case?

**Yes**, both are functionally equivalent. The first will be more efficient, since it does a `force_create` so Django will not first check if it can update in the database.

Indeed, if we look at [the implementation <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/django/django/blob/86561844ce66cda3e6a8c22d4ace4c2d1bc1f2e7/django/db/models/query.py#L643C1-L651C19) of the [**`.create(…)`** method <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#create), we see:

> ```
> def create(self, **kwargs):
>     """
>     Create a new object with the given kwargs, saving it to the database
>     and returning the created object.
>     """
>     obj = self.model(**kwargs)
>     self._for_write = True
>     obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
>     return obj
> ```

hence `.create(…)` will call `.save(…)` internally.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying and code pointers!